# Locking orientation of a single view in Sencha touch

Tags: android, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, screen-orientation

I am developing a sencha touch application and currently deploying it in Android device.
So i wanted to lock the orientation of only one view in it to Landscape mode
while the rest of the views will work normal. Is it possible to do that?

I can lock the whole app in landscape mode by writing

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

But how to do it for a single view?

Comment: You cannot. You need to layout that view to your needs (e.g. set height and width and center it horizontally). Then you can detect the orientation and might have to rotate the container by 90deg.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cordova can use a plugin: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/net.yoik.cordova.plugins.screenorientation

Usage (copied from readme):

```
// set to either landscape
screen.lockOrientation('landscape');

// allow user rotate
screen.unlockOrientation();

// access current orientation
console.log('Orientation is ' + screen.orientation);
```